# simple facebook logout returns called without an access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
<a href="#" onclick="FB.logout(function(response) { window.location.reload(true);});"><b>logout?</b></a>
```

Returns: FB.logout() called without an access token.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/):

> FB.logout will log the user out of both your site and Facebook. **You will need to have a valid access token for the user in order to call the function.**

Since the method logs the person out of Facebook, you first need to have the user log in and give permission to your application (via [`FB.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)), before they can be logged out.

What are you trying to accomplish?